# (Saltstack cmd.run 'chef-client --force-formatter doc') outputs the same chef client error

Tags: shell, chef-infra, salt-stack

I'm trying to make a script that runs a salt command on each server that has a failing chef-client run, however, each server i'm running the command on, outputs the same error message.

The command i'm running is --

```
for i in `knife status |grep hours | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d ',' -f 1`; do echo $i; salt "$i" cmd.run 'chef-client --force-formatter min' > $i.txt; done;
```

This will create a separate file containing the output for each server it runs on. The output is different each time, but all servers have the same error.

The error -

```
Recipe: salt::_setup?[0m
  * ohai_plugin[salt] action create
    * directory[/etc/chef/ohai/plugins] action create (skipped due to not_if)
    * cookbook_file[/etc/chef/ohai/plugins/salt.rb] action create (up to date)
    * ohai[salt] action reload
      ?[32m- re-run ohai and merge results into node attributes?[0m
?[0m
?[0m  ?[0m
  Running handlers:?[0m
  Running handlers complete
?[0m  Chef Client failed. 2 resources updated in 09 seconds?[0m
```

Now, if I ssh into that server and run chef-client manually, it doesn't fail on that part of the chef run.

Has anyone ever experienced this before and if so, how did you fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to remove the force formatter and turn the log level up to debug. Might show you the actual error.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually fixed it by adding `chef-client --force-logger -F doc`